# Importing a schema that imports another schema using the original namespace

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd, nokogiri, xml-namespaces

I have a collection of schemas that I am trying to use to validate an XML document using Nokogiri.

I have a top-level schema with the namespace `http://example.com/root`. It imports another schema, Extension.xsd, with a namespace `http://example.com/extension` and includes the schema Types.xsd (which obviously has a namespace of `http://example.com/root`).

The Extension.xsd schema, with a namespace of `http://example.com/extension`, imports the schema Types.xsd, with a namespace of `http://example.com/root`.

When I try to get Nokogiri to load the root schema it complains -  `Element import: The schema document Types.xsd cannot be imported, since it was already included or redefined`.

When I get rid of the import statement from the Extension.xsd file Nokogiri says that references to the namespace `http://example.com/root` aren't allowed because nothing was imported. 
When I get rid of the include statement from the root schema file Nokogiri says that an element used in the root schema from Types.xsd doesn't resolve to an element declaration.

Any idea how I can get Nokogiri to accept this schema structure? Is this even valid schema?

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly valid to have cyclic xs:import declarations in a schema, indeed, as this example shows, it is often necessary. I don't know Nokogiri, so I don't know if there is a fix.